# Getting something to work with something else

Tags: terminology, programming

What is the proper way of conveying that I'm starting the task of getting some component to work or to be compatible with another component?
Having an app that was developed for iPhone to work on Android, would be **Porting**.
Having 2 pieces of software work together would be **Integration**. 
I need to convey that I want a piece of software that is using a specific hardware module (a microphone) for its function, to also work with a different module (another microphone).

What would the correct term for this be?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sonja, welcome to EL&U. For this kind of question, it's important that you [edit] it to add a sample sentence that shows how you want to use the word, so that you avoid getting answers that (for example) offer a verb when you want a noun. E.g. *the zarb component will be able to ____ with the gizmotic input.* For further guidance, see [ask], and don't miss out on taking the site **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: I'd generally say that you are *interfacing* the two components/devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you could be looking for is ***interoperable.***

> if two products, programs, etc. are interoperable, they can be used together:
>   interoperable with sth The program was not interoperable with other software.

[-Cambridge on-line](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interoperable)